# Use container params in docker-py run

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

a basic question that I can't found in the docs, how to pass the container params to the docker-py `run` function:

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

We can run in a terminal the next line and will works:

```bash
docker run -e POSTGRES_DB="db" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="postgres" -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD="trust" -e POSTGRES_USER="postgres" postgis/postgis -c max_worker_processes=15
```

If we try to use docker-py we can do:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(
      "postgis/postgis:latest",
      environment = {
        'POSTGRES_DB': "db",
        'POSTGRES_USER': "postgres",
        'POSTGRES_PASSWORD': "password",
        'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD': "trust"
      }
    )
```

There we can send almost all params to the container creation, but still can't found how to pass the `-c max_worker_processes=15`. How can we send that params to the container?

The `run` function has a `command` params, but does not work. I tried concat that to the image name, nothing. I can't found examples too D:

Thx!

Comment: In the `docker run` syntax, anything after the image name is in fact interpreted as the command, and I'd expect something like a `command=['-c', 'max_worker_processes=15']` option to work.  What have you already tried here?

Comment: Yes, I tested it, was weird, the command was "executed" but the app didn't started, very weird, now works, and before no...!!!

Comment: now works..., so, we need to send it as a list, you can post it as a answer? and says why can't use str, if I found why before uses list fails, I'll complement the question.

Comment: seems, if we send a wrong param, we can get very weird errors, and maybe even none of them D:

Answer (score 0):

Anything that appears after the image name in the `docker run` command is interpreted as the "command" part of the container setup; it overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`, which may be specially interpreted by the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.  In the various Docker SDKs, you'd pass this as a `command` argument.

In docker-py specifically, the [`client.containers.run()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) method takes a `command` keyword argument.  While the documentation says it accepts either a string or a list, you'll get the most consistent behavior if you split the command into a list of words yourself, and pass that list as arguments.  (There are potentially significant security risks from assembling a command line via string interpolation, and using a list avoids many of these as well.)

```py
container = client.containers.run(
      "postgis/postgis:latest",
      command=['-c', 'max_worker_processes=15'],
      environment={...}
)
```